# How can I import php class to rootpay.php class in prestashop

Tags: php, inheritance, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to add ***/var/www/html/prestashop/webs/modules/rootpay/override/Rootpay/Client/Service/EcomCheckoutFormServiceClient.php*** class to ***/var/www/html/prestashop/webs/modules/rootpay/rootpay.php***.

I use import in rootpay.php class like that

```
require_once _PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'rootpay/override/Rootpay/Client/Service/EcomCheckoutFormServiceClient.php';
```

EcomCheckoutFormServiceClient.php class:

```
<?php

namespace Rootpay\Client\Service;

use Rootpay\Client\Configuration\ClientConfiguration;
use Rootpay\Client\HttpClientTemplate;

class EcomCheckoutFormServiceClient extends BasePaymentServiceClient
{
    public static function fromConfiguration(ClientConfiguration $configuration)
    {
        return new EcomCheckoutFormServiceClient($configuration, new HttpClientTemplate());
    }
}
?>
```

when I opened module page in admin page. I'm see this error:

> [PrestaShop] Fatal error in module file
>   :/var/www/html/prestashop/webs/modules/rootpay/override/Rootpay/Client/Service/EcomCheckoutFormServiceClient.php:
>   Class 'Rootpay\Client\Service\BasePaymentServiceClient' not found.

BasePaymentServiceClient use EcomCheckoutFormServiceClient same namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Autoloader in Prestashop has no clue about namespaces unfortunately.
You'll have to include all the dependencies at the top of `rootpay.php`.

I assume you're trying to include a "module" which is not Prestashop-compatible.

So at the top of `rootpay.php` you'll have to include:

```
<?php 
require_once _PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'rootpay/override/Rootpay/Client/Configuration/ClientConfiguration.php';
require_once _PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'rootpay/override/Rootpay/Client/HttpClientTemplate.php';
require_once _PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'rootpay/override/Rootpay/Client/Service/BasePaymentServiceClient.php';
require_once _PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'rootpay/override/Rootpay/Client/Service/EcomCheckoutFormServiceClient.php';
```

If your whole "module" is based on namespaces, I'm afraid you'll have to rewrite most of it.